# Can I create a layer like on websites using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layer

I want to create a layer in Java Swing which will be displayed when I move my mouse over a specific region on editor pane.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You must create a Component to draw whatever it is you want to show, and set it as the glasspane of a frame. I have created a loupe this way.
For more information, see [here](http://www.johnloomis.org/cpe101/notes/Swing/rootpane/rootpane.html).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solutution is to use a [JXLayer](https://jxlayer.dev.java.net/) framework